# Button Unresponsive

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, button, authentication

I have two rather basic questions I believe which needs answering:

1) When I run my emulator on the home screen my SignIn button is unresponsive and I am unsure why as I have tried alternative methods but whenever I click nothing happens and no error is showing. Code is shown below:

```
package com.techblogon.loginexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity 
{
    Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         // create a instance of SQLite Database
         loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
         loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

         // Get The Reference Of Buttons
         btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIN);
         btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);

        // Set OnClick Listener on SignUp button 
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            /// Create Intent for SignUpActivity  and Start The Activity
            Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUPActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUP);
            }
        });
    }
    // Method to handleClick Event of Sign In Button
    public void signIn(View V)
       {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
            dialog.setTitle("Login");


            final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
            final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

            Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIN);

            // Set On ClickListener
            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get The User name and Password
                    String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                    String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                    // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                    String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

                    // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                    if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        Intent ii=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,MainMenu.class);
                        startActivity(ii);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Close The Database
        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

Could somebody provide me with the best sqlite database viewer for eclipse, I am looking to view the records of the database I have created on my emulator

My XML is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello, Welcome"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignIN"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Sign In" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignUP"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Sign Up" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml as well..

Comment: @AndroSelva thanks, it is now shown above

Comment: @AndroSelva I have attempted to resolve your issue using the onClick xml below but now this seems to be cusing my emulator to crash. Thanks for your help as I am new to Android and looking for basic help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing an attribute in xml for `buttonSignIN` button

```
android:onClick="signIn"
```

Try this,

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignIN"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:onClick="signIn"
        android:text="Sign In" />
```

You need to understand the difference between setting clickListener in java code and setting a attribute from xml for the button click. These are two different ways in which you could achieve click events for any element.